# Looping an animation in javascript continuously

Tags: javascript, animation, dom

My question is how to loop an animation continuously. For example please follow the link below of W3School where a simple box moves from top to bottom and then stops.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_animate_3

But what I can't figure out is how to make this box animation non stop i.e. after it goes to the bottom it again moves up to its starting place and the animation continues forever.

Comment: What is your code. Also, we shouldn't have to visit a link to answer your question (what if the link goes dark)

Comment: Why are you writing your own animation code instead of just using CSS transitions or animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make these adjustments to the JS:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
var pos = 0;
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

function frame() {
  if (pos == 150) { pos = 0; }
  pos++;
  elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
  elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
}
```

```css
#container { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: relative; background: yellow; } #animate { width: 50px; height: 50px; position: absolute; background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div id ="container">
  <div id ="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok understood, but i dont want it to like bounce. After coming to the bottom i want it to start again from the initial position. What do i have to do?

Comment: @AbhrapratimNag Oh, ok, it's even easier. I changed my answer to do that.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i was seeking. Though i guess it is forbidden to say thanks here, but still, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `clearInterval(id);` that stops the animation timer and in its place add this `pos = 0;` to reposition the box every time it reaches the corner.

Answer (score 1):

Change script to this and it won't stop anymore. runAlready is needed to lock appearing of the second rectangle and `pos=0` in the if statement set the coordinate of the rectangle to the top left corner.

```
var runAlready=false;
function myMove() {
  if(!runAlready){
  runAlready=true;
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      pos=0;
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The setInterval(frame, 5) tells the program to call the frame() function every 5/1000th of a second. That is what creates the animation.

The clearInterval(id) function tells it to stop the animation.

Take a look at the change I added below. It uses a variable named 'direction' to change the direction of the box. Rather than stopping the animation when the box gets to the LR corner, it reverses the direction and keeps going.

```
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  var direction = 1;
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 0){
        direction = 1;
    } else if(pos == 350){
        direction = -1;
    }
    pos += direction; 
    elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
    elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
  }
}
```